# Is it possible to pass a Flask session to another .py-File which is not in the routing?

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-login, flask-session

I have an auth.py file where I store

```
session["current_user"] = user_data
```

If the user logs in I can see the session data in the console. How can I pass this session data to another file `test.py`?

In `test.py` some processing happens and not routed, since the user doesn't needs access on this.

Comment: This is too vague. How do you want to call this other code?

Comment: The docs say it works somehow by just importing the session module from flask e.g. "from flask import session". If I could import it from auth.py would be also fine.

Comment: That works *when you are inside a request*. How would you expect it to work if you weren't in a request. What session data would even be used?

Comment: Actually the session data will be stored just once and will be only read once. If I could assign it to a variable and import it in test.py would have helped

Comment: Then it's not *session* data. Just store it in the database somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you call a function within that file while a request is being processed (i.e. from one of your endpoints), it will have access to the session.

If you do not call it while a request is being processed, it will not have access to the session and you cannot do anything about it.

The reason is that on every request, the browser sends you a cookie. In this cookie there is a unique identifier that allows Flask to populate the value of `session` differently for each browser.

If you're not handling a request, you do not have a cookie, so you can't get a value in `session`.